# How to compare and find the highest average number of a value occurance in SQL for specific months?

Tags: sql

I am fairly new to SQL and need help to find which customer has the highest average number of event occurring by month in the years (2019 - 2020) and which is the top 3 busy month every year?

Please note one customer can have multiple event_IDs.

Table Snippet:

| event_ID | cust_ID | event_datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc123 | cus11 | 2019-03-13T00:00:00 |
| abc124 | cus12 | 2020-05-23T02:34:35 |
| abc125 | cus457 | 2018-12-12T22:12:23 |
| abc126 | cus11 | 2017-01-07T13:54:56 |
| abc127 | cus7897 | 2021-07-11T04:43:23 |

I need to find the customers having the highest average number of events in the respective month( cust with highest number of events on avg in 2019, 2020, 2021).

| month | cust_ID | avg_num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cus11 | 9345.8 |
| 2 | cus4563 | 11898.5 |

I have tried using CTE and window functions but couldn't figure out the logic to get to the result, any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
For clarification, my example is just a snippet of the table, the actual table has more than a few million rows, I need the customer who has the maximum number of events occurring on average over month 1,2,3,.. and avg_num will have the average value of the number of event for the cust_ID with max number of event-[ (num of event in 2019 + 2020 + 2021)/3 ]

Comment: Where should avg_num come from, it's not related to anything in your table. Your example shows 2 events for cus11, one in May 2020 and the other in January 2017. I have no idea how that could result in 9345.8

Comment: @FrankHeikens my example is just a snippet of the table, the actual table has more than a million rows! I need the customer who has the maximum number of events occurring on average over month 1 and avg_num will have the average value( for the cust_ID with max number of event- (num of event in 2019 + 2020 + 2021)/3. Hope that clears it

Comment: Please only add the relevant product tag to your query!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT  cust_id
    ,   COUNT(*) AS number_of_events
    ,   EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MAX(event_datetime)) last_year_for_cust_id
    ,   EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MIN(event_datetime)) first_year_for_cust_id
    ,   CAST(COUNT(*)  AS DECIMAL) / (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MAX(event_datetime)) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MIN(event_datetime)) )
FROM    table_name
GROUP BY    cust_id
ORDER BY    cust_id; -- or something else
```

I didn't test it, no idea what brand of database you use and no [DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14) was available.